# Application on Blackberry bold does not scroll horizontally

Tags: blackberry

I am developing an application using Blackberry 5.0 APIs.  I am having HorizontalFieldManager to which I am adding 2 labels and a Buttonfield.  I have set `HORIZONTAL_SCROLL` to both the Screen as well as to the Manager.

On the simulator I am successful to some extent to scroll horizontally.  I click on the label and drag it left and right.  Then it scrolls.  I don't see HorizontalScrollBar in the Screen.

When I run the application on device (Blackberry Bold 9000) it will not scroll horizontally.  I don't know how to drag and move it to the left or something like that as there is no scrollbar visible.

Can anyone suggest if Horizontal Scrolling is possible with 5.0 APIs and Blackberry Bold 9000?

Answer (score 0):

To add scroll bar you must include a flag in the constructor:

```
HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR);
```

You could also include `Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH` to let it use all the available space.

About the bold, make sure at least some of the fields in the manager are focusable.